# Button click outside gridview is not prompting message for correct row in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a `asp.net Gridview` where there are multiple rows. Also outside gridview there are 2 buttons such as `Approve` and `Reject` respectively. And there are `checkbox` in every rows.

So, what I want is, IF user is not checking `checkbox` and directly clicking on either approve or reject button, I should get prompt alert.

> But the issue here is, If I have 3 rows in that same gridview and while check the middle row checkbox and click on the button, it still gives me that prompt. So, how can U stop that prompt.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="rptHotoIPDataInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="appRejTableOuter appRejTable" Visible="true"
                                AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="rptHotoIPDataInfo_PageIndexChanging"
                                DataKeyNames="SAP_ID" OnRowEditing="rptHotoIPDataInfo_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="rptHotoIPDataInfo_RowUpdating"
                                OnRowCancelingEdit="rptHotoIPDataInfo_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="rptHotoIPDataInfo_RowDataBound"
                                OnRowCommand="rptHotoIPDataInfo_RowCommand" EnableViewState="true">

                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="appRejTable">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="appRejCheckbox" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="50px" Visible="true">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_ID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rejected Remarks" HeaderStyle-CssClass="appRejTable">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" Rows="3" Text='<%# Eval("REJECT_REMARKS") %>' runat="server" CssClass="appRejInput"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SAP_ID" HeaderText="SAP ID"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CHANGEREQUEST_ID" HeaderText="Change Request ID"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="R4GSTATE_CODE" HeaderText="State Code"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HOTO_STATUS" HeaderText="Hoto Status"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CR_Justifications" HeaderText="CR Justifications"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="APPROVE_REJECT" HeaderText="Status"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_UPDATED_BY" HeaderText="Last Updated by"></asp:BoundField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnApproveSite" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-blue" Text="Approve"
                                    CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("SAP_ID") %>' OnClick="btnApproveSite_Click" />

                                <asp:Button ID="btnRejectSite" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-blue" Text="Reject"
                                    CommandName="Reject" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("SAP_ID") %>' OnClick="btnRejectSite_Click" />
```

Also below is the C# code.

```
protected void btnRejectSite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strRemarks = string.Empty;
    string strID = string.Empty;
    string strCurrentUser = string.Empty;
    string strBtnReject = string.Empty;
    bool isUpdateRow = false;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in rptHotoIPDataInfo.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
            TextBox txtRemarks = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtRemarks");
            strID = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("lbl_ID") as Label).Text;

            strBtnReject = btnRejectSite.Text;

            if (chkRow.Checked == true && strBtnReject == "Reject")
            {
                strRemarks = txtRemarks.Text;
                strCurrentUser = CurrentUserName;
                int intGroupID = CurrentUserGroupID;

                if (strRemarks != "")
                {
                    isUpdateRow = UpdateRejectInfo(strID, strRemarks, strCurrentUser, intGroupID, strCurrentUser);

                    if (isUpdateRow)
                    {
                        BindHotoIPNonIPSubmit();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Alert", "<script>alert('Rejected Remarks cannot be blank');</script>", false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Alert", "<script>alert('For Rejection, first you need to check the Checkbox');</script>", false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling prompt alert inside your loop, if you dont select even one checkbox then you will definitely get alert.

What you should do is call prompt alert outside of your loop if no checkbox is selected. Like this :

```
bool chckedOrNot = false;
foreach (GridViewRow row in rptHotoIPDataInfo.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
            if (chkRow.Checked == true)
            {
                chckedOrNot = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

if(!chckedOrNot)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Alert", "<script>alert('For Rejection, first you need to check the Checkbox');</script>", false);
}
```

Also you can implement this code as per your requirements, I just wanted to tell that you need to call alert outside your loop to achieve desired results.

Comment: Tried with your code, even after checking the second checkbox, I am still getting the alert

Comment: @hud Bro you might be doing something wrong bcz the code I gave you is absolutely correct and I have been using this logic too in my project and this is the same code I have been using. Can you provide me your code after this change ?

Comment: yes I missed inside if part where it setting value as `true`